# How I can get the top view controller in React Navigation (Stack navigation)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am trying to implement react-native-msal in webview (WKWebView) over the screen for login but I am struggling to find a way to get the top view controller to pass it as a parent view.  With another navigation (react-native-navigation) the top view is a class UINavigationController, but that's not the case with react-navigation. Here is the file that I must update and add the logic for this react navigation library:
https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal/blob/v4.0.4/ios/UIViewController%2BRNMSALUtils.m

I tried with RNSNavigationController class but it's not working as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.